# How homeomorphism from discrete space X to Y, definy Y as discrete space too?

Tags: general-topology

Consider $ h:X \to Y $ as homeomorphism. Show that, if X is discrete space, then Y is also discrete.

I'm trying to use the fact that $h^{-1}$ is continous and $h$ is also bijective, but in my proof there is some mistake, because from it, i can deduce that $Y$ don't have to be a discrete space, but just with more elements, so i can make $h$ bijective and contionous

Comment: Well, what is your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will use the fact that $g= h^{-1}$ is continuous.

For any $y\in Y$, $\{y\} = g^{-1}(\{g(y)\})=g^{-1}(\{h^{-1}(y)\})$. Now as $X$ is discrete, the singleton set $\{h^{-1}(y)\}$ is a open set, so by using continuity of $g$ we get that $\{y\} = g^{-1}(\{h^{-1}(y)\})$ is an open set in $Y$.

Any arbitrary open set of $Y$ is a union of points of $Y$, so it is a union of open sets and hence is open.